# If importing from another component, props don't work

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

I am passing `props` to my component `CustomText`

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

interface CProps {
  weight?: 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900;
  children?: any;
  className?: string;
}
const CustomText = ({ weight = 400, className, children }: CProps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(className);
  }, []);
  return (
    <Text
      className={className}
      style={{
        fontFamily: `Poppins_${weight}${
          weight === 100
            ? "Thin"
            : weight === 200
            ? "ExtraLight"
            : weight === 300
            ? "Light"
            : weight === 400
            ? "Regular"
            : weight === 500
            ? "Medium"
            : weight === 600
            ? "SemiBold"
            : weight === 700
            ? "Bold"
            : weight === 800
            ? "ExtraBold"
            : "Black"
        }`,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
};

export default CustomText;
```

If I call it like this, it doesn't work:

```js
<CustomText className={"text-6xl"}>
  Face<CustomText className={"text-red-600"}>Med</CustomText>
</CustomText>
```

I am using it with nativewind.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The whole `CustomText` component is not showing? The `fontFamily` is incorrect or the `className` styles don't work?

Comment: FontFamily and className not working